# <HTML> and <BODY>: Why are there no new lines?

Tags: html, line-breaks

So I read that `<html>` and `<body>` are block level elements, just like `<div>` and `<p>`.

I understand that block level elements start a new line.

For example `aaa<div>b</div>ccc` looks like this:

```
aaa
b
ccc
```

So, why don't `<html>` and `<body>` add two lines to the top of your html page?

Comment: They're simply defining tags, they don't really put content anywhere.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Block level elements don't "start new lines"... they simply expand to both sides indefinitely until the hit a container element or the sides of the display (`width:100%`)... because of this, they have the effect of "pushing" any other content down below them, or dropping below any inline content that immediately precedes them. It also means that block-level elements will only "push down" sibling-level elements.

`<html>` and `<body>` elements have no siblings, only children, so they don't need to displace anything.

Here's a graphical representation of what's happening:
[image]

Given this markup:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <div>&nbsp;</div>
  <div>&nbsp;</div>
  <div style='width:45%; float:left;'>
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
  </div>
  <div style='width:45%; float:left;'>&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nice graphic! (more characters)

Comment: Awesome answer. Thanks I think I understand now. So, by default, block level elements are set to 100% width which is why they push themselves , and everything after it, down? unless you change the widths?

Comment: Ok, to play the devils advocate here, if you did <html>data and stuff<body>...</body></html>, in theory would the body be on a new line than "data and stuff"?

Comment: Yes, most browsers will then push the body block below the text. If you do any server-side programming without an error-handler, you'll notice that error messages `print`ed to the page will appear above the `<body>` (and `<html>`) tags because the server is sending `error message text<html>...</html>` back to the browser.

Answer (score 2):

Think of it this way:

```
<div>
    <div>Text</div>
</div>
```

There is only one line of text:

> Text

This is just like the case when you have any text in the body:

```
<html>
    <body>Text</body>
</html>
```

When the text is in the child element, no new lines are introduced.

Answer (score 0):

They are block elements that define the page. Browsers control how they want to view it. You might find some awful browser that displays the `<body>` by adding new line (it is possible). However, your main focus is to consider the `<body>` and `<html>` tags as a tags that displays everything on the screen. 
I would also like to add that you can use the  tag to fit the browser screen completely by using

```
body {padding:0;margin:0;}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Block level elements by default (i.e., when CSS is not used to change this) imply *line breaks* before and after. They do not imply *empty lines*.

So when you have `<div>foo</div>`, then “foo” appears at the start of a new line, and it also ands a line, i.e. any text after it is on the next line. But this does not mean creating empty lines. If you have `<div>foo</div><div>bar</div>`, then “foo” and “bar” appear on consecutive lines, with no empty line between them.

The `html` element as such does not generate visible content; only the `body` element inside it is shown. And the `body` content starts at the start of a page, which counts as starting on a new line. Whether there is a `<body>` tag or not is immaterial; there is always the `body` element, which starts on the first line.

Comment: "The html element as such does not generate visible content; only the body element inside it is shown." See http://jsfiddle.net/NxSm6/